# TypeError: no numeric data to plot in horizontal bar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I have this dataset

```
    Variable    Value
0   x1  0.001092
1   x2  0.000001
2   x3  0.002040
3   x4  0.000021
4   x5  0.000000
```

I want to plot a horizontal bar chart:

```
df.plot(x = "Variable", y="Value", kind="barh")
```

but I am getting the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-0c2ee6896cfe> in <module>
----> 1 df.plot(x = "Variable", y="Value", kind="barh")

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    953                     data.columns = label_name
    954 
--> 955         return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
    956 
    957     __call__.__doc__ = __doc__

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py in plot(data, kind, **kwargs)
     59             kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
     60     plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
---> 61     plot_obj.generate()
     62     plot_obj.draw()
     63     return plot_obj.result

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py in generate(self)
    276     def generate(self):
    277         self._args_adjust()
--> 278         self._compute_plot_data()
    279         self._setup_subplots()
    280         self._make_plot()
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py in _compute_plot_data(self)
    439         # no non-numeric frames or series allowed
    440         if is_empty:
--> 441             raise TypeError("no numeric data to plot")
    442 
    443         self.data = numeric_data.apply(self._convert_to_ndarray)

TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```

I hope you can help.

Comment: `Variable        object` and
`Value    float64`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine for me.  I would have thought you have strings in your Value column, but apparently that's not the case. Copy and paste the dataframe-from-dictionary from my code below.  If you can't plot it, then there is a problem with your environment.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Variable': {0: 'x1', 1: 'x2', 2: 'x3', 3: 'x4', 4: 'x5'}, 'Value': {0: 0.001092, 1: 1e-06, 2: 0.00204, 3: 2.1e-05, 4: 0.0}})
df.plot(x = "Variable", y="Value", kind="barh")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What does `df.dtypes` look like? (I overlooked the the `kind='barh'` argument in the first answer, sorry)

(I know this should be a comment instead of an answer but I don't have enough reputation yet to comment)

Edit (original answer):

You're trying to plot the 'Variable' column, which seems to contain strings and not numeric data. The `plot()` function expects numerical data for its x argument)

Comment: thanks, jrbergen. I swapped the two variables and it worked. It is fine, jrbergen. The only thing that I would suggest is would be just to add an explanation (as your did previously) and the solution (just swapping x and y)

Comment: You're welcome, but it's weird because I should have been wrong according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) which states either can consist of labels or positions.

Comment: You should not have to swap x and y for a horizontal bar graph.  There is a problem with your environment.

Comment: @LdM can the selected answer be changed? Mine is wrongish.